# MVC controllers bubbling back into the router?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a URL scheme like this:

```
website.com/keywords
```

and I also have specific controllers:

```
website.com/controller/action
```

Sometimes the keywords may look an awful lot like controller URLs, or have some kind of "/url/thingy" on them.  All of the keyword URLs will be stored in a database and return static content.  What I'd love to be able to do, is have the "keywords" controller match first (it just uses {*}), and if the URL isn't found in the database, pop back out to the router, and let the matching continue.

I've got a workaround now which puts the universal matching router at the very end, and doing a 302 redirect to the proper controller, but that is a longer round-trip time and isn't necessary if I can pop back out.

Comment: You can add a custom constraint to the route, which can match against a list. You could even do a lookup to, for example, a database in the constraint - but as everything will passing through the routing engine I'm not sure that's wise from a scalability point of view unless you efficiently cache the lookups. In any case this is likely to get better answers on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that i dont want to do the leg work on this one because i would love to have the answer as well but i did have this bookmarked on the subject. [custom route constraint](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx)

if you go down about half way you can see how to create your custom route contraint; just search for ***Listing 2 – NotEqualConstraint.cs*** then you can pass in a cached list of those keywords or just have the custom route constraint hold onto the list of keywords itself.

Comment: We ended up putting the catch-all at the bottom, as we realized it was only necessary for roughly one page hit per visitor, since after that we're going to be using the proper routes.  Still, have the answer.